# When using Invoke-Expression inside a function it doesn't do anything

Tags: powershell

If I do the following I get what is supposed to do (get the content from a file with curl and then execute the content as powershell code).

```
$Uri = "some-arbitrary-uri.com/file.txt"
Invoke-Expression (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri).Content
```

But when putting it inside a function it stops working.

```
function Invoke-FileContentExpression($Uri)
{
    Invoke-Expression (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri).Content
}

Invoke-FileContentExpression -Uri $Uri
```

Comment: Based on your examples, you didn’t populate $uri in the “not working” version

Comment: Besides, it is quite dangerous to use `Invoke-Expression` unless you are **absolutely** sure the content is safe to run...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) commented, `Invoke-Expression` [can be dangerous](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/why-invoke-expression-is-evil#:%7E:text=Invoke%2DExpression%20is%20a%20very,it%20from%20some%20web%20site.) to run. The issue you are facing has nothing to do with `Invoke-Expression`, it has to do with scopes. Functions execute in their own scope. See the example below.

```
# variable is populated in the current scope
$var = 'hello world'
Write-Host Var contains $var # Var contains hello world

# var is populated in the functions scope and is gone after the function ends
Function Write-HelloWorld {
    $var = 'HELLO WORLD'
}

Write-Host Var contains $var # Var contains hello world
```

So the `Invoke-Expression` is doing what you told it in the function scope and is gone when the function ends. If you want to pull that up to your scope, just [dot source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.2#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) it.

```
function Invoke-FileContentExpression($Uri)
{
    Invoke-Expression (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri).Content
}

. Invoke-FileContentExpression -Uri $Uri
```